# Paypal Transaction Search API not returning customer's email or phone number

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm using Paypal's transaction search API to retrieve transaction history for my account. However, sometimes all of the customer's info is not returned in the payer_info object, such as their phone number or email. This missing info shows up when I look at the transaction inside Paypal, but not the API. The call I'm making is a pretty simple cURL call:

```
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2021-06-08T00:00:00-0700&page_size=20&page=1&fields=all&end_date=2021-06-10T23:59:59-0700&transaction_id=<transactionid>');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer $access_token";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The only things returned every time in the payer_info object are account_id, address_status, payer_status, payer_name[] and country code.

It seems as though I can get this info for transactions that were processed through Paypal checkout, but not ones that were done with a credit card (even though Paypal still processes our credit card sales).

I'm not sure what I need to change to make sure I'm always retrieving the full payer_info object. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Sean